# Important functions defined via derivatives

Tags: calculus

I know that there are important functionswhich are defined via the improper integral of some other function (gamma for example), but I'm wondering if there are also useful functions that are defined via the derivative?

Comment: Not quite sure if this qualifies, but the digamma function, $\psi(x)$ is given by $$\psi(x)=\frac{d\,\log(\Gamma(x))}{dx}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take for example the Hermite polynomials $H_n(x)$. Some ways to state their definitions through derivatives are :
$$
H_n(x)=(-1)^ne^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\cdot e^{-x^2}=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\big(x-\frac{d}{dx}\big)^n\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=\big(2x-\frac{d}{dx}\big)^n\cdot1
$$
Lots of other special functions can be defined in similar ways.

Comment: +1 The Legendre and Laguerre polynomials can be defined in a similar way.

Comment: True. These are usually called Rodrigues' formula
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula